# Custom Directive developed in Angular 9 not working in mobiles

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9, mobile-browser

I have developed a custom directive in angular 9 to enter **only digits and 1 decimal**. The directive works flawlessly in desktop but not in mobiles (as if the directive is not even present in the input field). I used keydown event as the host. Is this an issue in Angular side? Any suggestions or existing posts that I need to refer.

**EDIT**

```
@Directive({ 
    selector: 'input[allowCurr]',
    host: { '(keydown)': 'allowND($event)' } 
})
export class AllowCurrDirective { 
    @Input() allowCurr: string;
     /* Rest of my Logic here */ 
}
```

I added this much because I had put alert inside my allowND function, it is going inside it but event.key, that I had used to capture user key input, is coming undefined.

Comment: please add some code showing your attempts

Comment: did you forget to add `()` after your `@Input` in the real code too, or just here? (It should be `@Input()`)

Comment: Yes I forgot to add here only. But what I wanted is to detect event.key in case of mobile browsers. Any workaround for thoat, or its an angular issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this. I had to use event.target.value alongwith input event to meet my requirement for allowing only numbers and one decimal to be typed inside input box.

:: Research ::

Open this [MDN URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) in your smartphone browser. You can see that on input event, KeyboardEvent.data works as KeyboardEvent.key in desktop. That means you can see the key you pressed in your smartphone keyboard. (I confirmed it in W3schools try-it editor also, in my smartphone). But the thing is KeyboardEvent.data is not compatible for iPhones. That means, I can neither use event.key nor event.data. Input event is not cancellable (that means event.preventDefault() wont work either) so whatever you type if it doesn't get through the condition, the input value should be:

```
let targetVal = event.target.value;
event.target.value = targetVal.substring(0, targetVal.length -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

May you could try with **HostListener**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "input[allowCurr]"
})
export class AllowCurrDirective {
  @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"])
  allowND(e) {
    console.log(e.key);
  }
  @Input() allowCurr: string;
  /* Rest of my Logic here */
}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paxuyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: I tried with that too, still not working.

Comment: I think given sample works for chrome https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paxuyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: For Desktop/Laptop browser it will definitely, but not for android smartphone chrome/edge browser and my problem is only for smartphones. However, don't know for sure whether it will work on iPhone Safari too. Lashan, try to open your url in your smartphone and ev.key alert will give undefined.